Using different Kestrel settings in different appsettings.json files
I am developing a Windows service in .NET 6. This service is hosting a Web API.
In UAT and PROD env, this Web API will be exposed using HTTPS. On my computer, it will be exposed using HTTP.
I'm using XL Deploy to deploy my app in UAT and PROD. XL Deploy is replacing tokens in my appsettings file while deploying.
Here the Kestrel section in the appsettings.json file:
"Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
        "HttpsInlineCertStore": {
            "Url": "{{API_URL}}",
            "Certificate": {
                "Subject": "{{CERTIFICATE_SUBJECT}}",
                "Store": "My",
                "Location": "LocalMachine",
                "AllowInvalid": "false"
            }
        }
    }
},

Here the Kestrel section in the appsettings.Local.json file:
"Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
        "Http": {
            "Url": "http://localhost:9200"
        }
   }
},

When I run this app in local, I get the error:

Invalid url: '{API_URL}'
System.FormatException: Invalid url: '{{API_URL}}'

When I watch the configuration instance in my program.cs, I see:

We can see that configuration is looking for Kestrel in the appsettings.json file.
I don't understand why. I expected the Kestrel section to be completely overridden.
I have another very similar Windows Service hosting a Web API the same way, and I don't have this issue.
Do I have a problem understanding how configuration file overriding works? If so, how do I get an Http node in one case and an HttpsInLineCertStore node in the other?
Any help will be greatly appreciated
Thanks

For testing purpose, did you try using "HttpsInlineCertStore": undefined in appsettings.Local.json file?

That's the default behaviour, importing each .json file as name / value pairs in your configuration. Perhaps you should rename appsettings.json to appsettings.SAMPLE.json or something.

UPDATE
I recommend dynamic read configuration at the application level.
// Load the base configuration file
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

// Load additional configuration files based on the current environment
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

You are missing "" for the url. Modify it and test again.
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:9200"
      }
    }
  }


Well,, It is a copy paste problem, there are present in my file :)

@TFK May I know if you have a chance to check the solution above? If you need further help, please let me know, have a nice day.
